# Angular CLI HTTP Client Get data but not refreshing object

Tags: c#, angular

I'm working on  angular cli 7  program
I used Httpclient for Read Data From Web Api  .net
My method on server return json value

```
getTicket(ticketId: number) {
return this.http.get<TicketModel>(
  SERVERURL/ticketId}
).pipe(map(res => res["result"] as TicketModel));
```

}

// create object modelfor binding

```
  selectedTicket: TicketModel = new TicketModel();
```

// call the method for get ticket and set on selectedTicket Object

```
        this.accountService.getTicket(ticketId).subscribe(res => this.selectedTicket = res);
```

service get data but not refrishing `this.selectedTicket` 
and I most click on UI or other buttons to refresh object

[image: data from server]

```html
<ul class="list-inline">
   <li>
     <i class="fa fa-calendar-alt kt-font-brand "></i>
     <span style="color:#a7abc3;">تاریخ :
     </span>
     <span> {{selectedTicket.requestTime | agoTime}}
     </span>
   </li>

   <li>
      <i class="fa fa-briefcase kt-font-brand"></i>
      <span style="color: #a7abc3;">واحد : </span>
      <span>{{selectedTicket.departmentName}}</span>
   </li>
```

Comment: Need all related code! and Sample JSON in the form of code not images!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to know for sure, since you haven't published your component's code. But, if you're using the changeDetectionStrategy OnPush, then this can happen if you haven't injected a ChangeDetectorRef into your component and used it's markForCheck method when the the template needs to be rerendered.

So, first add this to your component's constructor parameters:

```
 private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
```

Then change your code that sets this.selectedTicket to this:

```
this.accountService.getTicket(ticketId).subscribe(res => {
  this.selectedTicket = res;
  this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck()
);
```

Comment: Another issue could be if you are passing the Ticket Model as an input into another component.